Python Floor Division Seems incorrect?
I was noticing that in some situations floor division (the // operator) seems to behave incorrectly. Here is one example:
>>> 59 // 0.2
294.0

Two things - one, the answer is just wrong. The correct answer is 295 (note that 59 / 0.2 gives the correct result of 295.0). The second issue is that this result is a float, not an integer.
I cannot for the life of me figure out how this is happening. Is it a bug? Some weird behavior when a float is in the divisor? I am using 3.12.

since floating point math works for this specific example, it seems like its different. I even note that in the question - 59 / .2 works, 59 // .2 does not.

Sorry I went a bit fast, retracted my vote but looks like it still left an automatic comment... Deleted now.

Might be relevant: https://discuss.python.org/t/integer-division/23140/2

And from the docs: "If one of the dividends and divisor is float, the floor division will return a float."

Just FYI, this isn't version-specific. 2.7 behaves the same.

@Julien Where is that quote from in the docs? I googled it but only found this AskPython page. The closest thing I found in the docs is: "The ... division ... operators yield the quotient of their arguments. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type." under Binary arithmetic operations. "Common type" in this case means "rational number", i.e. float.

When you use 0.2 in source code, Python converts the decimal numeral 0.2 to floating-point. Python does not specify what floating-point format implementations use, but it is most commonly IEEE-754 binary64, called “double precision.”
The closest value representable in binary 64 to 0.2 is 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125.
So 59 // 0.2 divides 59 by 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125. The result before truncation is a little less than 295, so 294 is the correct result.

See my answer for more. 50/.2 is in fact exactly 250. in Python (try it),, so it's important to understand why the context matters.

@TimPeters: I entered this answer because your answer does not show the actual value that the source text 0.2 is converted to. And it does not say why divmod(59, 0.2) produces (294.0, 0.19999999999999674) instead of (295, 0). Knowing the specific step that source text is converted to a floating-point format is important.

Understood. This gets tricky to understand in full. What you're missing ;-) is that the expression math.floor(59/0.2) returns exactly 295.0.  That the literal 0.2 is, internally, a little larger than a fifth is actually irrelevant to that outcome. The "real reason" is that the internal implementation is doing more work, precisely and only to ensure that an approximation to the identity I gave will hold. In fact, in floatobject.c, float_floor_div() calls _float_div_mod(). // and % have to be computed together to keep them as mutually consistent as possible.

@TimPeters: I am not missing it. I am quite conversant with floating-point arithmetic and the details of rounding.

Not to be difficult, but that's not particularly relevant here. This is entirely due to how float_floor_div() is implemented. Which I wrote decades ago, so I know everything about it ;-) The true reason is that math.fmod(59.0, 0.2) returns 0.19999999999999674, where the exact value of the result is, mathematically, an exact integer multiple of the exact value 0.2 denotes smaller than 59. That's what drives it all: a mathematically exact result for %. The result for // is then picked to make the stated identity approximately true. math.fmod() is generally exact (no rounding).

@TimPeters: All that is needed to understand // is that it produces the mathematical floor of the quotient of its operands. While the relationship x == (x//y)*y + (x%y) is maintained, it is not needed to understand floor division.

The identity is needed to understand how the floor is computed in CPython, which may well be more than the OP wants to know. CPython does not emulate fp arithmetic, or have access to FPU directed rounding modes. It's all standard, portable C that's worked everywhere for some decades. It does rely on the platform libm's fmod() being exact.

Stick to ints ;-)
>>> divmod(59, .2)
(294.0, 0.19999999999999674)

That's the heart of it. Floor and mod aren't isolated operations in reality. After q, r = divmod(x, y), Python strives to get as close as it can to satisfying the mathematical identity x == q*y + r, and
>>> 294 * .2 + 0.19999999999999674
59.0

The identity can be satisfied exactly when only ints are involved, but throw a float into the mix and it's not always possible to meet all desirable outcomes simultaneously.
In this specific case, 59/.2 is not mathematically equal to 295, but to a real number slightly smaller than that (the float .2 is not one fifth):
>>> from decimal import Decimal as D
>>> D(59) / D(.2)
Decimal('294.9999999999999836242103868')

That's why the floor is 294 - because that is the floor in reality.
